# The well-ordering principle can be used to show that there is a unique gcd of two positive integers...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question**
The well-ordering principle can be used to show that there is a unique gcd of two positive integers. Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers, and let $S$ be the set of positive integers of the form $as+bt$, where $s$ and $t$ are integers.

a) Show that $S$ is non-empty.
b) Use the well-ordering property to show that $S$ has a smallest element $c$.
c) Show that if $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, then $d$ is a divisor $c$.
d) Show that $c|a$ and $c|b$.
e) Conclude from (c) and (d) that the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ exists. Finnish the proof by showing that this gcd of two positive integers is unique.

> This is my first use of well-ordering principle so I need
> confirmation. More about my problem of this question in the section
> **Problem** below.

**My Attempt**
a) $S$ is non-empty since $s$ and $t$  in $as+bt$ can be any non-negative integers.

b) From (a), since $S$ is non-empty set of positive integers, by Well-Ordering principle there is a least element $c$.

c) Since $d|a$ and $d|b$,
$$a = dk_1, k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$b = dk_2, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Thus,
$$c = as + bt = (dk_1)s + (dk_2)t = d(k_1s) + d(k_2s) \equiv 0 (\bmod d)$$

d) Suppose $c \nmid a$, then $a = qc + r, 0 < r < c$. Suppose now $r \in S$, this is a contradiction since since we've already established that $c$ is the least element in set $S$.

e)

- Existence: We have shown a least element $c$ in a non-empty set $S$, such that $c\mid a$ and $c \mid b$. Other divisors such as $d$, divides $a, b, c$, thus $d \leq c$, hence gcd $c$ exist.
- Uniqueness: Suppose $\exists e \mid \gcd(a, b) = e$ then $$e \mid a, e \mid b \rightarrow e \mid c,$$ which is true if and only if $e \leq c$, considering $\gcd(a, b) = e$, thus $e = c$.

**Problem:**
(a) and (b) was my very first use of well ordering principle (at least consciously) thus I need confirmation its being used right. (c) I'm quite confident so its unlikely that its wrong. (d) I'm a little shaky on that, is that also a correct use of well ordering principle? (e) I can't find anything wrong with it, but if its wrong just point it out.

Comment: If I could give $+10$ to this post, I would. This is a perfect example of how to show work when asking a question. :)

Comment: @bof I guess what I meant is any non-negative integers would do since $a$ and $b$ are already positive integers.

Comment: "**Any** non-negative integers" won't do, because $s=t=0$ is no good. Anyway, to show that $S$ is nonempty, all you have to do is exhibit **one** element of $S$. Why not just say "$S$ is nonempty because $a+b\in S$, as we can see by taking $s=t=1$"?

Comment: In "(b)", you should say "has a least element, $c$", so that we know what $c$ refers to in part "(c)". In part "d", best to say "...then $a = qc + r$ for some $q \in \mathbb Z$ and some $r$ with $0 < r < c$. Your part-d argument isn't clear to me .. needs further detail, I believe. But the parts a/b stuff is fine (i.e., the use or well-ordering), subject to bof's comment. (And I agree with anorton completely -- congrats!)

Comment: @bof I don't get why "Any non-negative integers" won't do. Isn't Wel-Ordering Property is "Every non-empty set of non-negative...", if $s=t=0$, then $c = 0$, which is non-negative, enough for $c$ to be in set $S$.

Comment: A bit of a quibble about logical wording, but in part (d) we do not "suppose" that $r \in S$, as since $c \in S$ we can write $c = ta + sb$ we know we can re-arrange that equation to $$0 < r = qc + a = [q(t+1)]a + qsb \in S$$. Suppose should be restricted to the single assumption used for the contradiction.

Comment: $0\notin S$ because $S$ is **defined** as "the set of **positive** integers of the form . . .". Good thing, too. If $0$ were allowed as an element of $S$, then of course the least element of $S$ would always be $0$, but that won't work as a greatest common divisor.

Comment: Actually, the best way to do part (a) is to take $s=a$ and $t=b$ and show that $a^2+b^2\in S$. This way we can see that we don't really need to assume that $a$ and $b$ are both positive, all we need is that they are not both zero.

Comment: @bof I see. I'll take that into account. Cheers.

Comment: A search for squares arithmetic progression found [this paper](https://math.ucr.edu/~res/math153-2019/history07b.pdf) with a parameterization of primitive sets of squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a, you didn't use the well-ordering principle.  You showed there was at least one element of $S$ by exhibiting one.  It would be a bit better to say "take $s=1, t=0$, then $as+bt=a$, so $S$ is not empty." but you have the idea.  b is correct as stated-you used the well ordering principle correctly.  c is fine as well.  For d you don't justify that $r \in S$, but you can.  This is the critical point.  You have $r=a-qc$  Now substitute in $c=as+bt$ and you justify what you were assuming.

Comment: Hello! The OP says "We have shown a least element c in a non-empty set S, such that c∣a and c∣b. Other divisors such as d, divides a,b,c, thus d≤c, hence gcd c exists." The OP initially assumed c to be the smallest element of the set. Isnt it then contradictory to the line "Other divisors such as d, divides a,b,c, thus **d≤c**". Shouldnt d always be equal to c, since a number less than d doesnt exist?  Im a mere beginner in number theory, please bear with me!

Comment: @newbie105:  $c$ is the smallest element of the set of numbers you can form as $as+bt$.  Other divisors $d$ of $a,b$ are not members of $S$, but they are $\le c$